# Mac display flickering

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, flickr

I have a 2016 Macbook Pro 13" touch bar. Recently I have started facing issues with my display. It appears as if the display turns ON and OFF over and over again; I mean like every second or two. I started my Mac in safeboot and didn't face the issue there. I have performed SMC reset, and NVRAM reset but to no avail.
Reinstalled MacOS (Mojave) all over again after full format of my drive but the issue still persisted. So, I thought there could be some issue with this new OS and installed (after fully formatting the drive) the good old Sierra with which my system originally came. But the issue is still there. Also note that the screen doesn't flicker in one more case where I observed was while watching a video but if I just run the video in background then again screen starts to flicker.
I am really scared to start my mac now. [image]

Edit: Following are the extensions that are present in normal startup and not in "safe boot": 
[image]

Comment: The display in attached image appears to be partially lit but it was in a process of just getting ON and OFF. I mean the image is during transition. Flickering rate was high.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with the video chip.

Here is how to tell...
  Shutdown your machine.  Hold down the shift key.  Poweron.  Bootup will be longer.
    Wait awhile while you harddrive is being checked.
  An article on how to boot into safe mode.
    http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455

Runs OK in safe mode...
Running in Safe mode leaves out some video drivers.  Which results in your machine not using advanced video hardware. As luck would have it, you can run the safe mode video drivers in normal mode.

Here is how:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/16057567#16057567

Look through the above thread.  See the second page.  You don't have to read through the first page.  Just go to the part where I try a solution that works.

Using the safe mode video driver results in these limitiations:
  -- OpenGL acceleration is not supported on this mac
  -- Your mac lacks quartz extreme acceleration

Comment: I went through the page suggested by you. As per my understanding, I did as follows: 1. Used "csrutil disable" command in Recovery HD mode. 2. Created a new folder in "/System/Library" with name "Disabled Extensions" 3. In "/System/Library/Extensions" copied (and later deleted) all the files starting with name ATI in it i.e. ATIRadeonX2000.kext, ATIRadeonX2000GA.plugin, ATIRadeonX2000GLDriver.bundle, and ATIRadeonX2000VADrive.bundle, and pasted it in the "/System/Library/Disabled Extensions". Restarted the Mac, problem still persists 

Comment: Just to verify, your machine works fine in safe mode?

Comment: You need to boot in safe mode and record what all your extensions are.  You boot in regular mode and see what the extensions are now.  You delete files accordingly.

Comment: Kindly help me; which of the extensions (question has been edited) are safe to remove without hampering the mac's performance.

Comment: Any suggestions please.

Comment: Help please guys :(